# EJS (embedded javascript) vs backbone.js -- quick summary of differences

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, ejs

What's a summary of the differences between EJS and backbone.js for building client-side javascript applications?

Comment: I am sorry for the close vote but this is not constructive. Simply visiting the respective homepages reveals the two have completely different goals and are not comparable.

Answer (score 2):

EJS is a templating framework like JAML, JST, mustache, handlebars ... Backbone is far more than that, Backbone is able to use EJS templates to render its views and data but create an application framework around it. Backbone gives you the tools to create an event driven application, whereas all EJS does is take data and transpose it into html.

Backbone uses underscore.js' template functionality by default, which you can see here: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template . You can easily switch it out for any other templating engine.